# Excel: How to create a Search Bar to Allow me to search and send me to certain tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel, search, tabs

I have a master Excel sheet with over 150 Tabs.  I am trying to create a search bar that will allow me to easily view these named tabs in alphabetical order and take me to those tabs once clicked.

Comment: What version of Excel you are using? In my Excel 2016 I can use Find (Ctrl+F) function just fine. Why does this not working for you?

Comment: How about an alphabetized table of contents in some column, each cell would have a hyperlink to a tab ??

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following VBA code to create a list of the tab names as hyperlinks in a new sheet called 'Index', then manually sort it.

```
Sub generate_DOWN_list_with_hyperlinks_of_sheets_in_the_Active_Workbook()
Dim ws As Worksheet

If MsgBox("Do you want to create a list, starting in the active cell, of all sheets in this work book?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'insert name
        ActiveCell.Value = ws.Name
        'insert hyperlink
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'" & ws.Name & "'!A1", _
            TextToDisplay:=ws.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next ws     
End Sub
```